# DSC error for post deployment SQL configuration

Tags: azure, arm, dsc

I am deploying SQL server 2016 with ARM to Azure. Trying to implement post deployment configuration with DSC module.

DSC config:

```
    xSQLServerSetup 'InstallDefaultInstance'
    {
        InstanceName = 'MSSQLSERVER'
        SQLCollation = 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'

        SQLSysAdminAccounts = $SqlInstallCredential
        SourcePath = 'C:\SQLServerFull\'
        DependsOn = '[WindowsFeature]NetFramework35','[WindowsFeature]NetFramework45', '[xDisk]TVolume'
    }
```

And get the following:

```
"error": {
  "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "Conflict",
      "message": "{\r\n  \"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\r\n    \"details\": [\r\n      {\r\n        \"code\": \"VMExtensionProvisioningError\",\r\n        \"message\": \"VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'Microsoft.Powershell.DSC'. Error message: \\\"DSC Configuration 'Main' completed with error(s). Following are the first few: The network name cannot be found.  Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string. Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.\\\".\"\r\n      }\r\n    ]\r\n  }\r\n}"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: why are you sure that this snippet is to blame?

Comment: I think `SourcePath = 'C:\SQLServerFull\'` this should be `Path = 'C:\SQLServerFull\'`

Comment: error is very clear `Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.`